# How to fetch image in sql server using vba excel

Tags: image, excel, vba

I'm newbie .
Currently I'm to trying to import the image [varbinary(max) as the data type] from sql server 2008 into the vba excel. I get "Type Mismatch" error.

Here I'm provide the code that I have

```
serverConn   'call the connection function

' open connection
objConnection.Open strConnectStr

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim stm As ADODB.Stream

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set stm = New ADODB.Stream

Dim sqlquery As String

sqlquery = "SELECT [well_img] FROM well_image WHERE [img_id] = 2"

rs.Open sqlquery, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

stm.Type = adTypeBinary
stm.Open
stm.Write rs("well_img").Value   'write bytes to stream
stm.Position = 0

Sheet1.display_img.Picture = stm.Read   'this line is the problem ("Type Mismatch error")

stm.Close
rs.Close
objConnection.Close

Set stm = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set objConnection = Nothing
```

The display_img is Image ActiveX control.
Hopefully somebody can help me, I'm really need to know the answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Gord's answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443467/how-to-load-picture-into-ms-access-image-control-from-ado-recordset-field) suggests something like this should work, so it may be how you're referencing your image control that's the problem.  Try `Sheet1.OLEObjects("display_img").Object.Picture = stm.Read`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion answer, but sadly the problem is still not solved. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: You could try saving the image to a temp file and loading it from there.  Are you sure the image control is compatible with the format of your image?  What type of format is the image?

Comment: I'm also thinking about that, but I'm decide to save the image as a binary type in sql server. I have done to upload/save the img into the sql server db. But I'm still fail to display the image. The type of image is .png and .jpg. Thank u for helping.

Comment: I meant save the image to a temp file after pulling it out of the database.