# Excel Vba. Get ADODB stream from Image control (not with LoadFromFile)

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

With the following function I can load a picture from file and encode it to base64:

```
Public Function EncodeFileBase64() (strPicPath As String) As String
    Const adTypeBinary = 1          ' Binary file is encoded

    ' Variables for encoding
    Dim objXML
    Dim objDocElem

    ' Variable for reading binary picture
    Dim objStream

    ' Open data stream from picture
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile (strPicPath)

    ' Create XML Document object and root node
    ' that will contain the data
    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument")
    Set objDocElem = objXML.CreateElement("Base64Data")
    objDocElem.DataType = "bin.base64"

    ' Set binary value
    objDocElem.nodeTypedValue = objStream.Read()

    ' Get base64 value
    ' EncodeFileBase64 = objDocElem.Text
    EncodeFileBase64 = Replace(objDocElem.Text, vbLf, "")


    ' Clean all
    Set objXML = Nothing
    Set objDocElem = Nothing
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Function
```

As I would like to **resize the image before** encoding it I guess that the 'logic' should be:

**- 1 -** Load the image by selecting it using a dialog, resize it and display it into a `image.picture` control:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonImage_Click()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Submit"
        .Title = "Selezionare un'immagine"
        .Filters.Add "Image", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png", 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            ' file has been selected

            ' Resize somehow the image

            ' display preview image in an image control
            Me.Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom
            Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(1))
        Else
            ' something
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**- 2 -** Get the image data by loading it from the Image Control `Me.Image1.Picture`

**- 3 -** Pass the loaded data to the `encode_to_base64 function`

The problem is that I don't know how to change the `ADODB.stream` code above so that it does not loads the picture from a file but it loads the picture from `Me.Image1.Picture` and then encodes it to base64. It should be possible as I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443467/how-to-load-picture-into-ms-access-image-control-from-ado-recordset-field).

Comment: Don't really understand. Now I have to load the picture two times: one for show it in `Me.Image1.Picture` and one for encode it base64. But as said I would like to **resize** the image and **then encode it** so I need to have a resized image before passing it to the encoding function. For this reason I would like to grab the data stream from `Me.Image.Picture`.

Comment: Since you **know how to read a file in 64b mode**, I meant 1. read file, 2. resize, 3. write back to file, 4. read in 64b mode

Comment: Ok got it. This could be a "last resort" work around.

Comment: **SOLVED.** [Take a look at my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351838/excel-vba-save-resized-image-to-file).