# How to retrieve an image from an Access Database in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, picturebox

I'm trying to retrieve an image stored in an Access Database to a Picturebox.
I'm not very fluent with this language, but my current code is as follows:

```
Private Sub lstUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstUsers.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    dt = runSQL("Select * from tblUser where UserName = '" & lstUsers.SelectedItem.ToString & "'")

    txtForename.Text = dt.Rows(0)(2)
    txtSurname.Text = dt.Rows(0)(3)
    txtCode.Text = dt.Rows(0)(6)
    txtFinish.Text = dt.Rows(0)(7)
    Dim data As Byte() = DirectCast(dt.Rows(0)(8), Byte())
    Using ms As New MemoryStream(data)
        Me.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    End Using

End Sub
```

When I try to run it and I select a username I get the following error message pointing to Image.FromStream(ms):

> Parameter is not valid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443467/how-to-load-picture-into-ms-access-image-control-from-ado-recordset-field)?

Comment: Just checked it, but I honestly don't understand much.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19999243/2144390) shows how to convert an array of bytes into a PictureBox `.Image` via a `System.IO.MemoryStream`.

Comment: @GordThompson I have made the following improvements but I keep getting the error Parameter is not valid.